# mysql group by based on another column

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

Let's say I have the following table Records:

```
    Id   |   machine   |   manual   |
-------------------------------------
    1    |    1        |    false   |
    2    |    2        |    false   |
    3    |    3        |    false   |
    4    |    4        |    false   |
    5    |    1        |    true    |
```

I want to retrieve a distinct table based on the machine column but when it comes to "chose" between manual: false or true the true prevails over false.

```
    Id   |   machine   |   manual   |
-------------------------------------
    5    |    1        |    true    |
    2    |    2        |    false   |
    3    |    3        |    false   |
    4    |    4        |    false   |
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a mysql boolean column is a tinyint type you can do this.

```
 SELECT max(id), machine, max(manual) FROM machines group by machine;
```

[image: example output source]

Comment: @Danubio Despite your 'acceptance', I very much doubt that this is really what you want.

Comment: @Strawberry must confess that I didn't run the query myself, and noticed that there weren't any non aggregated columns etc so upvoted. Now upvoting yours :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT machine,MAX(manual) manual FROM my_table GROUP BY machine ) y
    ON y.machine = x.machine 
   AND y.manual = x.manual;
```